# Flutter hours and minute count issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to sum the hours and minutes so I am doing this like ill convert hours in second and minutes in second then sum it

```
var totalServiceSeconds = minsSeconds + hoursSeconds;

var c = Duration(seconds: totalServiceSeconds);
print('c ${c.toString()}');
```

it's showing `c 25:05:00.000000` which is correct

Know I need to show this as hours and minutes in the text widget. So I am converting to DateTime like this

```
var format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
DateTime totalServiceTime = format.parse(c.toString());
```

But it's printing it like this `totalServiceTime 1970-01-02 01:05:00.000`

This issue is only when the hours are 24 or more. If my hours are 24 then it's showing 0 and if greater than 24 then it's showing 1 2 so on. I know it because it's considering 24 as 0 but what can I do about this?

I want to show 24 if it's 24 hours or if greater than 24 like 26 need to show 26.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to convert it into a `DateFormat` because time steps of 24 hours is how they count a full day. Instead you should format `var c` as shown below

```
var totalServiceSeconds = minsSeconds + hoursSeconds;

var c = Duration(seconds: totalServiceSeconds);
print('c ${c.toString()}');


String FormatDuration = "${c.inHours}:${c.inMinutes.remainder(60)}:${(c.inSeconds.remainder(60))}";
print(FormatDuration);

String FormatDuration2 = "${c.inHours} hours ${c.inMinutes.remainder(60)} minutes ${(c.inSeconds.remainder(60))} seconds";
print(FormatDuration2);
```

The output will then be

```
c 25:05:00.000000               <-------previous
25:5:0                          <-------new option 1
25 hours 5 minutes 0 seconds    <-------new option 2
```